# Add path segment at last part of URL with ZnUrl

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I am using Pharo 3 and I want to add a path segment as the last part of an URL for example http://example.com/myapp?key1=param1&key2=param2 and I want to get /myParam added to the last part. With ZnUrl I tried with #addSegment:

```
(ZnUrl fromString: 'http://example.com/myapp?key1=param1&key2=param2')
  addPathSegment: 'myParam'
```

but results in

```
 http://example.com/myapp/myParam?key1=param1&key2=param2
```

How could I configure the ZnUrl to get?

```
http://example.com/myapp?key1=param1&key2=param2/myParam
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you are describing is not a valid URL:

[image: URL explanation]

So what you are talking about is not an addition of a path segment, but rather string concatenation.

You can consider doing:

```
ZnUrl fromString: 'http://example.com/myapp?key1=param1&key2=param2/myParam'
```

or if you get a `url` from somewhere else,

```
(self asString, '/myParam') asUrl
```

should work too.

You can also do more magic to get everything to work, but in a first place you have to redesign your URL structure, to fit the standards (if you can influence it)